# Using the JS Google API to add a contact but it never disconnects or signs out

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-api-js-client, google-contacts-api

Through many searches I've gotten the script in question to work as expected. If the user clicks on a button on my web page then a contact will be created in their Google Contact list (if authorized).

The problem I'm left with is that the authorization never expires. In that once successfully authorized the user can press the button many times, even come back to the page later in a different session, and it will never ask for authorization again.

Perhaps this is the intended behavior of the GoogleAPI but for my intended purpose I don't expect any more than 1 click and I would expect if the user came back to my page at a later time that they would be asked to authorize again.

Is this possible? I've tried the following ...

```
gapi.auth.signOut();
gapi.auth2.signOut();
gapi.auth2.disconnect();
```

revoking the token (see end of post)

... with no success.

Code can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/brian_hill/chvtmmjr/7/

```
function addContact(entry) {
  var config = {
    'client_id': '403037917634-qproaer1g5gcq83c941heo4q07olol23.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds',
    'cookie_policy': 'single_host_origin'
  };
  gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
    insert(config, entry);
  });
}

function insert(config, entry) {
  gapi.client.request({
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': '/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/',
    'headers': {
      'GData-Version': 3.0
    },
    'body': {
      'entry': [entry]
    },
    'callback': function(data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty('entry')) {
        var msg = "Your Google Contacts have been updated to include ";
        window.alert(msg.concat(data.entry.title.$t))
      } else {
        var msg = "Contact information could not be added for "
        window.alert(msg.concat(entry.title.$t))
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And the HTML

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>

<body style="background-color:rgba(32, 177, 17, 0.3);">
  <p>
    The button below will add a contact to your GMail contacts</p>
  <div style="width:150px">
    <script>
      function addJohn() {
        var entry = {
          "category": [{
            "scheme": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind",
            "term": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/contact\/2008#contact"
          }],
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "John Doe"
          },
          "content": [{
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "[Automatically Created]"
          }],
          "gd$email": [{
            "rel": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#other",
            "address": "john.doe@abcd.com",
            "primary": "true"
          }],
          "gd$postalAddress": [{
            "rel": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#home",
            "$t": "123 Main Street\nOttawa, ON\nCanada"
          }],
          "gd$phoneNumber": [{
            "rel": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#home",
            "$t": "555.123.4567",
            "primary": "true"
          }]
        };
        addContact(entry);
      }
     function addJane() {
        var entry = {
          "category": [{
            "scheme": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind",
            "term": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/contact\/2008#contact"
          }],
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "Jane Doe"
          },
          "content": [{
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "[Automatically Created]"
          }],
          "gd$email": [{
            "rel": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#other",
            "address": "jane.doe@abcd.com",
            "primary": "true"
          }],
          "gd$postalAddress": [{
            "rel": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#home",
            "$t": "321 Unknown Street\nOttawa, ON\nCanada"
          }],
          "gd$phoneNumber": [{
            "rel": "http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#home",
            "$t": "555.765.4321",
            "primary": "true"
          }]
        };
        addContact(entry);
      }
</script>
    <button onclick="addJohn();">Add Contact - John</button>
    <button onclick="addJane();">Add Contact - Jane</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

(Note: Due to the nature of the GoogleAPI authorization process, it doesn't appear to work through JS Fiddle on either Chrome or Firefox --- I did get it to work on Microsoft Edge).

Thanks in advance,
Brian

PS. Adding my attempt for using the 'revoke' option. Which still doesn't work (I still don't get re-prompted for authorization) but also sometimes it works (updates addresses) and sometimes it doesn't.

```
function addContact(entry) {
  var config = {
    'client_id': '403037917634-qproaer1g5gcq83c941heo4q07olol23.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds',
    'cookie_policy': 'single_host_origin'
  };
  gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
    insert(config, entry);
  }).then(signOut);
}

function signOut() {
   $.ajax({
     'type': 'GET',
     'url': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
        gapi.auth.getToken().access_token,
     'async': false,
     'contentType': "application/json",
     'dataType': 'jsonp',
     'success': function (nullResponse) {
         window.alert('Disconnected');
     },
     'error': function (e) {
         // Handle the error
         console.log(e);
     }
   });
}

function insert(config, entry) {
  gapi.client.request({
    'method': 'POST',
    'path': '/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/',
    'headers': {
      'GData-Version': 3.0
    },
    'body': {
      'entry': [entry]
    },
    'callback': function(data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty('entry')) {
        var msg = "Your Google Contacts have been updated to include ";
        window.alert(msg.concat(data.entry.title.$t))
      } else {
        var msg = "Contact information could not be added for "
        window.alert(msg.concat(entry.title.$t))
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Revoke token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) instruction in OAuth 2.0:

In some cases a user may wish to revoke access given to an application. A user can revoke access by visiting Account Settings. It is also possible for an application to programmatically revoke the access given to it. Programmatic revocation is important in instances where a user unsubscribes or removes an application. In other words, part of the removal process can include an API request to ensure the permissions granted to the application are removed.\

To programmatically revoke a token, your application makes a request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke` and includes the token as a parameter:

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried that previously but I thought I would give it another try. I think one of my issues here is the order in which the callbacks are executed. If I include the revoke option then the operation will alternate WORKIING and NOT WORKING. But at no time does it ever ask me to re-authorize. I've added a "revoke" version to my original problem.